# Google Maps Javascript API - How to remove adult-related search results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I developed a maps application several months ago using the google maps javascript api and so far it's worked great with no complaints from our clients.

However, recently we got one complaint that our maps were bringing up adult-related places content. I'd like to completely remove these results. Our application is deployed to hundreds of clients so just removing the place marker based on it's id is not going to work for us.

Ideally I'd like to set a list of certain keywords to NOT search for - (i.e., 'sex', 'strip club', etc. - bars are fine.)

Right now we're using a keyword list such as ... Art Galleries, Bowling Allies, Casinos, Gyms, Movie Rentals, Movie Theaters, Museums, Night Clubs, Parks, Spas, Stadiums, Zoos ... for our entertainment section. Some adult-related places are popping up in these somewhere. (probably in movie rentals or night clubs)

Keep in mind that our app is using the **javascript** api places library here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

I've considered the idea of doing something like this...

if (results[i].name.search(/sex/i) == -1){if (results[i].name.search(/strip club/i) == -1){do something}}

But that isn't a very comprehensive option as alot of stuff would still get through.

Does anyone have any insight on how I might get around this? I don't think there is any native javascript maps api option for this. We're not using JSON so I don't think we can use a 'normal' search query.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I don't think there is any native way to do this but I'll share what I did as a work-around just in case anyone else stumbles upon this question...

```
<cfif entertainmentFilter EQ 0>
    <cfset Entertainment_sub = 'Art Galleries,Bowling Allies,Casinos,Gyms,Movie Rentals,Movie Theaters,Museums,Night Clubs,Parks,Spas,Stadiums,Zoos'>
<cfelse>
    <cfset Entertainment_sub = 'Art Galleries,Bowling Allies,Gyms,Movie Theaters,Museums,Parks,Spas,Stadiums,Zoos'>
</cfif>
```

I'm using coldfusion to set it here but it's a simple conditional statement that can be setup with any language.  Basically just have a 'filter' variable which when set to 1 removes any search terms that are more likely to find adult content.