# Google Maps Javascript API - Filter Adult Content / Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps - JavaScript API [text search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) to find placed near a location.. Below is the `request`

```
            // prepare request to Places
            var request = {
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);,
                radius: 5000,
                query: ["Entertainment"]
            };

            // send request
            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            var that = this;
            service.textSearch(request, function (results, status) {
                that.createMarkers(results, status, keyword);
            });
```

Everything works as expected. I get the results etc. However, Is there a way to filter out `Adult places` like strip club, bars etc? On digging further i found the `results array` contains place types with keywords like `night_club` etc. But not all strip clubs have the type `night_club` assigned to them, they are listed as `establishment` or `point of interest`.

Any idea how to filter these places via API or any other way?

I found just [one related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773735/google-maps-javascript-api-how-to-remove-adult-related-search-results) dated back to 2013, hopefully google has something by now?

Answer (score 0):

There's no classification like that built into Google's database or 'safesearch' options like web queries. You will have to make do with a limited list you put together yourself, or dive into ML([Library](https://github.com/harthur/classifier)). You could also make a list of place types that you want to include (basically all but 'bar' in this case) then iterate over it with a request for each, and recombine the results.

Comment: Yeah, thats the workaround i'm using already. Hoping to find something else